# Geodesics on a sphere

Tags: geometry

I'm given the following problem:

> Consider the curve $\theta = t, \phi = 0$ on the unit sphere.  At the point $t = \pi/4$, the tangent vector to the curve is $(1,0)$. A tangent vector of the form $(0, a)$ will be perpendicular to the previous tangent vector at this point. Given these 2 conditions, I have been asked to find a line/geodesic that passes this point such that such that the tangent vector of the geodesic is perpedicular to the tangent vector of the original curve at this point.

Is there a way to go about this problem without having to explicitly solve the geodesic equation?

Comment: The geodesics of a sphere are great circles.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have been unable to find a convenient equation for the great circles. Can you suggest one which I can use, given the specification of the problem/initial conditions, to write down the equation for the relevant great circlev

Comment: Write the equation of a curve on the sphere in spherical coordinates and express that it belongs to a plane through the origin.

Comment: Same question reworded: [Geodesics on a unit sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271135).